# Скроллить блок с position:fixed, когда его перекрывает такой же блок

Tags: html, css

Есть два блока. В одном блоке содержится текст, в другом просто фон немного прозрачный. Блоки могут перекрывать друг друга и из-за того что у одного блока есть фон, он перекрывает текст, а скролл у блока с текстом не появляется. Я хочу, чтобы когда блоки пересекались, у блока с текстом появлялся скролл

```css
.down-box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.up-box {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="down-box">
    SCROLL<br>
    SCROLL<br>
    SCROLL<br>
    SCROLL<br>
    SCROLL<br>
    SCROLL<br>
    SCROLL<br>
    SCROLL<br>
    SCROLL<br>
  </div>
  <div class="up-box">

  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пропишите блоку с текстом z-index:99999;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял.. То вы хотите сделать так, чтобы блок `.down-box` и `.up-box` делили всю высоту экрана, при `.up-box` всегда был прижат к нижней части экрана..
Если так, то есть несколько вариантов..

`position: fixed;`

```css
.down-box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 50px; /* отступ равен высоте блока .up-box */
  max-height: 100%; /* ограничим блок по высоте */
  overflow: scroll;
}

.up-box {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="down-box">
  SCROLL<br>
  SCROLL<br>
  SCROLL<br>
  SCROLL<br>
  SCROLL<br>
  SCROLL<br>
  SCROLL<br>
  SCROLL<br>
  SCROLL<br>
  SCROLL<br>
  SCROLL<br>
  SCROLL<br>
  SCROLL<br>
  SCROLL<br>
</div>
<div class="up-box"></div>
```

---

`flexbox`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
}

.down-box {
  display: block;
  width: max-content;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.up-box {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="down-box">
    SCROLL<br>
    SCROLL<br>
    SCROLL<br>
    SCROLL<br>
    SCROLL<br>
    SCROLL
  </div>
  <div class="up-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое )) Очень странно, что вы здесь обращаетесь на "вы"))